# How to use a Regex to check URL should begin & end with expected pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to check if URL is valid to match below pattern.

`https://xxx.abc.com/yyy/?&p=1000/1001`

How can i write the Regex to achieve?

**Expected**:

1. Starts with domain 'https://xxx.abc.com', '**xxx**' could be any name of sub-domain, '**abc.com**' should be fixed value.
2. Path /yyy could be any path, even sub-path should be allowed.
   https://xxx.abc.com/yyy/?&p=1000/1001
3. ?&p=1000/1001 should be ok with '**\?(\&)?p=\d+/\d+**'

Answer (score 1):

`/https:\/\/[a-z0-9]+\.abc\.com\/.*\?(\&)?p=\d+\/\d+/i`

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify any restrictions on xxx or yyy, I'm going to assume they should conform to something reasonable such as "1 or more alphanumeric characters or a dash/hyphen" or in regex: `[a-bA-B0-9\-]+` feel free to adjust that to anything else in the regex:

```
^https:\/\/[a-bA-B0-9\-]+\.abc.com/[a-bA-B0-9\-]+\/\?(\&)?p=\d+/\d+$
```

breaking it down:

- the `^` in the start and the `$` in the end are important because they make sure the regex matches the entire string you pass it (`^` binds to the beginning of the input string and `$` binds the end) without those, you might match any string that contains the URL as a substring
- the `[a-bA-B0-9\-]+` parts, as mentioned above match any sequence of alphanumeric or `-` characters. Note that if you are using a regex framework that allows you to run the regex case insensitive (e.g. a perl/javascript like regex `/regex/i` or in c# using  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) you can safely change this to `[a-b0-9\-]+`
- the rest is pretty self explanatory I believe...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this: `^https:\/\/\w+\.abc\.com\/[\w\/-]+\?\&?p=\d+\/\d+$`

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQcwX5/4) here

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your regex into two groups :

`^(https:\/\/[a-z0-9]+\.abc\.com)(\/.*\?\&?p=\d+\/\d+)$`

1 - The first group starts with domain `https://xxx.abc.com`

2 - The second group is the sub-path like `/yyy/?&p=1000/1001`

***[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/mCJIJ7/1)***